# Remove trailing spaces from a file or multiple files using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

How can I achieve the following two things with the help of a bat file:

1. Remove empty spaces only at the end of the a file.
2. Do this for the file or all files withing a folder (directory).

The file(s) may contain a continued string of text that may include spaces, *, >, ~, !, |, and ^.

The edited file(s) should remain with the same name. No need to create new files after the removal of the empty spaces.

This is what I have so far (with the help of other members) but it does not work if I call it from another bat file (remove_space.bat file_to_change.txt) where remove_space.bat is the file that contains the script and the "file_to_change.txt" is that file that has empty spaces at the end. If multiple files exist in the directory, the file names will be: file_to_change_#######.txt. Where the "#" is the counter or date/time stamp.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "spcs= "
for /l %%n in (1 1 12) do set "spcs=!spcs!!spcs!"
findstr /n "^" "%~1" >"%~1.tmp"
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
   (
    for /f "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("%~1.tmp") do (
      set "ln=%%L"
      setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
      set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
      set /a "n=4096"
      for /l %%i in (1 1 13) do (
       if defined ln for %%n in (!n!) do (
        if "!ln:~-%%n!"=="!spcs:~-%%n!" set "ln=!ln:~0,-%%n!"
        set /a "n/=2"
        )
      )
     echo(!ln!
     endlocal
  )
) >"%~1"
del "%~1.tmp" 2>nul
```

Comment: Now after you have told us what you want to do, what is your specific question? If you expect we do your work and write a script for you, you are wrong here, because StackOverflow is not a free code writing service. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here!

Comment: Yes, it can be done.  Handling special characters is challenging in batch files directly; I usually recommend writing a script to handle that in Visual Basic Script or PowerShell; if you have it, Perl is good at this as well.

Comment: Hi aschipfl, my specific question is how to do it. I've seen other questions from other members and their question is answered with a code.  I have the code but I need further help on getting my code to work for multiple files within a directory and to launch it from another bat file or application.  Thank you!